# Python 3 OOP - where does "super().__init__()" go exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am trying to make my sub-class work, but something is wrong with the inheritance. The number of args passed in should be 5: name, age, gender, title & salary

However, Python is saying

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

and I don't know why or how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

class Employee(Person):
    def emp_function(self, title, salary):
        self.title = title
        self.salary = salary
        super().__init__()   
     #Is this wrong? Where should this 'super()' go?

George = Employee("George", 30, "male", "Manager", 50000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`super().__init__()` should be in `def __init__` of Employee class

You need to create constructor for `Employee` class too.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender,title,salary):
        self.title = title
        self.salary = salary
        super().__init__(name, age, gender)   


George = Employee("George", 30, "male", "Manager", 50000)
```

Comment: Thanks, Akshay. Yes, this does work!....*but* shouldn't the sub-class only have the new attributes (title, salary) and not need all 5 attributes listed out? That would defeat the whole point of inheritance if you had to write them all out again on all sub-classes when they are defined in the super-class...?

Comment: @SamAndrew81 subclass will have all the attributes of parent class with some extra attributes that's the concept of Inheritance, `super().__init__()` will help you to initialize parent class attributes with single call.